# Question not exactly a duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

The question, [Running Jar files from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257694/running-jar-files-from-python) isn't a duplicate.

It is less about calling Java from Python and more to do with calling a subprocess, so the answer should be different.